# How to stopPropagation for element overlapping other element but not child of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu generated by WordPress. On sub menus creates next to an a element an ul.sub-menu element.
I want to use slideToggle animation for it(I will end up using hoverFlow plugin in the end, but when will behave as it should).

The order should be: [a.mouseenter][show menu], [a.mouseleave][but not over ul.submenu][hide menu], [ul.sub-menu.mouseleave][hide menu]

The problem is the a.mouseleave is triggered when mouse is over ul.submenu.

The only thing I have is that ul element overlaps a little over a element, it has position absolute.

I can't use stopPropagation because ul.sub-menu is not a child of a element.

For now the code I use

```
jQuery(function($) {

// will completely cover the a hovered element 
$('#access .sub-menu').append('<div style="
position: absolute;
top: -105px;
right: -2px;
height: 106px;
width: 92px;
background-image: url('images/transp.gif');
"></div>');

$('#access a').hover(function(){
    $(this).next('.sub-menu').hide().slideToggle();
},function(){
    $(this).next('.sub-menu').hide();
});

$('#access .sub-menu').hover(function(){
    $(this).show();
},function(){
   $(this).slideToggle();
}); 

});
```

html:

```
<ul>
<li id="menu-item-198" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-198">
<a href="/?page_id=194">Shop Online</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-248" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-248"><a href="/?page_id=230">Products</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-275" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-275"><a href="/?page_id=263">Procedures</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-284" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-284"><a href="/?page_id=279">Gift Cards</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you show the html code snippet too for clarification?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selector).hover(function(e){
 e.stopPropagation()
})
```

won't help?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.menu-item a').hover(function() {
    $(this).next('ul.sub-menu').show();
},
function(e) {
    $(this).next('ul.sub-menu:visible').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
});
$('ul.sub-menu').mouseleave(function(e) {
    $(this).hide();
});
```